# Postgresql - Optimize query with calculated columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

I have to create a view in postgresql with calculated columns, but my query is taking a very very long time to run.

I have a table called surveys which contains one entry for every survey.

Sno= Serial number of person who was called

survey round = surveys are conducted for multiple periods called rounds, upon which we need to group and calculate metrics

call_status=status of survey calls

I want to get stats per round like how many users were called i.e. unique sno, how many calls were completed, count per different call status values

My current query is =

```
select distinct  sc.survey_round, 
(select  count(distinct sno) FROM "Suvita".survey_call_details sc1 where sc.survey_round =sc1.survey_round  ) as "Total respondents call",
(select count(*) fROM "Suvita".survey_call_details sc2 where sc.survey_round =sc2.survey_round and sc2.iscomplete = 'Yes') as "Survey Completed",
(select count(*) FROM "Suvita".survey_call_details sc3 where sc.survey_round =sc3.survey_round)  as "Calls Attempted",
(select count(*) FROM "Suvita".survey_call_details sc4 where sc.survey_round =sc4.survey_round and sc4.call_status = 'Picked Up')  as "Calls Answered"  
FROM "Suvita".survey_call_details sc
```

Please suggest a better way to write these queries in postgresql.

Edit: I have got the answer.
Based on Alexey's response, I re-qrote the queries using count and sum and they worked really fast!!

```
SELECT sc.survey_round, 
    COUNT(distinct sc.sno) as "Total respondents call",
    COUNT(*) as "Calls Attempted",
    sum(CASE WHEN sc.call_status = 'Picked Up' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Calls Answered",
    sum(CASE WHEN sc.iscomplete = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Survey Completed",    
    sum(CASE WHEN sc.nominate = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Agreed to Nominate"
FROM "Suvita".survey_call_details sc
group by sc.survey_round  order by sc.survey_round desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you do not need subqueries to count something in one table, just use `CASE` statement with conditions in `COUNT`.

Second, `COUNT(DISTINCT sno)` can be slower then `COUNT(sno)`. To get distinct `sno` values you can use `JOIN LATERAL`, that would be used as a subquery.

Then your query become this

```
SELECT 
    sc.survey_round,
    COUNT(sc1.sno) as "Total respondents call",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sc.iscomplete = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Survey Completed",
    COUNT(*) as "Calls Attempted",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sc.call_status = 'Picked Up' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Calls Answered"
FROM "Suvita".survey_call_details sc
JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT DISTINCT sno 
    FROM "Suvita".survey_call_details 
    WHERE survey_round = sc.survey_round
) sc1 ON TRUE
GROUP BY sc.survey_round
```

Atlast, you should have indexes on `survey_round` and `sno` columns. With live data maybe complex index on `survey_round + sno` would perform better.